# Automatically subscribe users to MailChimp list?

Tags: users, emails

I would like to automatically subscribe all newly registered users to a MailChimp mailing list.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Install the [MailChimp Subscribe](https://github.com/aelvan/mailchimp-subscribe-craft/) plugin and add the following `users.onActivateUser` event listener to your site’s [Business Logic](https://github.com/lindseydiloreto/craft-businesslogic) plugin.

```php
craft()->on('users.onActivateUser', function(Event $event) {
    $user = $event->params['user'];

    if (!$user->admin) {
        $result = craft()->mailchimpSubscribe->subscribe($user->email, '');

        if (!$result['success']) {
            Craft::log('Couldn’d subscribe to MailChimp list: '.print_r([
                'errorCode' => $result['errorCode'],
                'message' => $result['message'],
            ], true), LogLevel::Error);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Hi Calcs, this is interesting. But I am such a newbie that I have no clue where to put this?! Could you please tell me in which file of the business logic plugin I have to paste this? And where would any error messages show up? What happens if a user is already subscribed? Will Mailchimp still send activation Emails? Could you add a Name as well?

Comment: You’d add that event listener to your plugin main class (BusinessLogic.php) `init()` method, @outline4. For your other questions please refer to the Mailchimp plugin documentation or ask a new question here using the tag plugin-mailchimp.

Comment: Error messages would be logged to your craft.log file with the above code, but you can do whatever you want in the case of `$result->success` returning a false value.

Comment: Thanks.. Man... I can't find a BusinessLogic.php file, nor an init() method... Gosh... I feel so dumb... All I see is these 4 files: BusinessLogicPlugin.php, BusinessLogicController.php, BusinessLogicService.php, BusinessLogicVariable.php... and in them I can't find any init() stuff... Could you please retry to help me? I'm such a dushbag ;(

Comment: Sorry I meant the BusinessLogicPlugin.php file, create that method there @outline4

Answer (score 1):

**Update to carlcs answer:**

The new MailChimp Subscribe plugin sends an array as result instead of an object. So I had to go this way:

```
craft()->on('users.onActivateUser', function(Event $event) {
    $user = $event->params['user'];

    if (!$user->admin) {
        $result = craft()->mailchimpSubscribe->subscribe($user->email, '');

        if (!$result["success"]) {
            Craft::log('Couldn’d subscribe to MailChimp list: '.print_r([
                'errorCode' => $result["errorCode"],
                'message' => $result["message"],
            ], true), LogLevel::Error);
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If it helps anyone else, full working code for this task as of 19/11/2019 in Craft 3:

Using the [MailChimp Subscribe](https://github.com/aelvan/mailchimp-subscribe-craft/) and [Business Logic](https://github.com/lindseydiloreto/craft-businesslogic) plugins, place the following near top of `BusinessLogic.php`:

```
// Make sure we have relevant Craft bits for use
use craft\services\Users;
use craft\events\UserEvent;
```

Then place the below subscription code within your `public function init() {}`:

```
// Add new user to Mailchimp on account activation event
Event::on(
  Users::class,
  Users::EVENT_AFTER_ACTIVATE_USER,
  function (UserEvent $event) {

    // get our user
    $user = $event->user;    

    // Grab easier reference to mailchimp-subscribe plugin
    $msPlugin = Craft::$app->plugins->getPlugin('mailchimp-subscribe');

    // Make sure plugin exists
    if ($msPlugin && $msPlugin instanceof \aelvan\mailchimpsubscribe\MailchimpSubscribe) {

      $listID = 'XXXXXXXXXX'; // mailchimp audience ID

      // Example data
      $result = $msPlugin->mailchimpSubscribe->subscribe($user['email'], $listID, [
        'email_type' => 'html',
        'language' => 'en',
        'vip' => false,
        'tags' => false,
        'merge_fields' => [
          'FNAME' => $user['firstName'],
          'LNAME' => $user['lastName']
        ]
      ]);

      // Handle outcome
      if (!$result['success']) {

        // Do something if failed (like output error to logs)

      } else {

        // Do something else if success...

      }
    }
  }
);
```

Thanks to all other contributors here - definitely got me moving in the right direction.